# How to combine data in different rows in to single row in rdlc?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a table in rdlc which is displaying result as shown below

[image]

I need the data in a single row

[image]

I gave group by but it is showing value in only 2 columns

Comment: This looks like a problem in the SQL.  Can you post the SQL you are using to populate this report?

Comment: Not that it can't be handled in SSRS, but it's better to handle in dataset. Do share the query.